# Yosemite Xampp PHP

Tags: php, mysql, osx-yosemite

Before I upgraded to Mac OSX Yosemite my XAMPP worked fine. I was able to write and test my .php files without issue. After the upgrade mySQL quit working. So, I downloaded and installed the newest version of XAMPP. This made it so that mySQL now works, however my .php files no longer function. When I open up a .php doc in any browser, while running XAMPP, it displays all of my code and the code does not run. What am I missing? Does anyone else have this issue, and if so, have you fixed it and how?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1. Make sure your PHP is installed correctly 2. Do you open your file in the browser or do you call your file over the localhost server?

Comment: Rizier123, you had it right on the second point. I kept trying to drop the file into my browser. When I called the path correctly/directly it's working again. I was so tripped up after the update to Yosemite that I was blaming everything on that. ^.^

Comment: Nice that i could help you! Have a nice day. (Made a answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the file over the server like this:

```
localhost/index.php  //example
```

and NOT the file this:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Sandbox/index.php
```